# Did I solve correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, vector-spaces, invariant-subspace

Q: Let $f:V\rightarrow V$ be a linear operator on real vector space $V$. Prove if dim$V\geq2$, then there exist invariant subspace of $V$, with dimension $2$.
*My approach*:
Induction: Basis - if dim$V=2$, we can take V be that invariant subspace, because if $v\in V$ then it is obvious that $f(v)\in V$.
Assumption - We assume there exist invariant subspace for every vector space such that dim$V=n-1$.
**Proof**

> Let $V_{n-1}$ be a vector space with dimension of n-1, and $W_{n-1}$, be the mentioned invariant space. Now:
> let $g:V_{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ be isomorphism, such that if $v\in V_{n-1}$ then $g(v)=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\ \vdots \\ a_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Now, let's define $g^*:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$
> recall that $f:V_{n-1}\rightarrow V_{n-1}$ have the invariant subspace $W_{n-1}$ such that if $w\in W_{n-1}$ then $f(w)\in W_{n-1}$. 
> Now, because of the isomorphism of $g$, if $w\in W_{n-1}$  then we will have some subspace $W^*_{n-1}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$, such that if $g(f(w))\in W^*_{n-1}$ then $g^*(g(f(w)))\in W^*_{n-1}$. Now, let $h:\mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be defined by $h(\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\ \vdots \\ a_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n-1})=\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\ \vdots \\ a_{n-1}\\a_n\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, for example: $h(\begin{pmatrix}4\\6\\1\end{pmatrix})=(\begin{pmatrix}4\\6\\1\\-12\end{pmatrix})$. Now, what i'm not sure, is if we can say that the linear opator $h^*:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $h^*\Bigg(h(g^*(g(f(w))))\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\Bigg)=(\begin{pmatrix}g^*(g(f(w)))\\a_n\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^n)$ have an invariant subspace $W^*_n$, such that dim$W^*=2$. I think that it can be true, because even though I am defining $h$ by some specific $g^*$, We know(by the assumption), that every $g^*$ have the invariant subspace $W^*_{n-1}$. From here, let's define $i^*:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow V^n$ be isomorphism, such that if $\begin{pmatrix}g^*(g(f(w)))\\a_n\end{pmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ then $i^*(\begin{pmatrix}g^*(g(f(w)))\\a_n\end{pmatrix})\in V^n$. For the last time, let's define $i:V^n\rightarrow V^n$ be a linear operator,  with some subspace $W_n$, such that, if $i^*(\begin{pmatrix}g^*(g(f(w)))\\a_n\end{pmatrix})\in W_n$ then $i(i^*(\begin{pmatrix}g^*(g(f(w)))\\a_n\end{pmatrix}))\in W_n$, and because dim$W^*_n=2$, we can conclude that for every vector space $V_n$ there exist some invariant subspace $W_n$ with dimesion $2$.$\square$

*Note that I know that there are already proofs of this question(or similar ones) on this site, I just want to make sure, that my proof is good!*

Comment: In your definition of $h$, what is $a_n$?

Comment: some real number.

Comment: It is hard to follow your proof. Analyze your reasoning on the first nontrivial case $n=3.$

Comment: I know it's hard to follow this proof, this is why I thought it would be best to ask it 
@RyszardSzwarc   here. Anyways, I don't think that it would be much different if I were to take n=3 or n=n, because it's not somehing like: proof that $1+2+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, and you can really see what's going on. But if you still think it will be easier to understand, I will try to do so, just if you could answer, it would be great.

Comment: It is hard to follow because you have worded it in a hard to follow way. May I suggest that you just prove it for $V = \Bbb R^n$ first, then expand that result to all finite-dimensional vector spaces in an obvious corollary? It is what you are apparently doing anyway, but would cut the length of your proof by more than half and drastically simplify your notations.

Comment: Your definition of $h$ makes no sense. When you define a function, the output has to be completely determined by the input. Your definition of $h$ adds $a_n$ as a new coordinate. But no expression for $a_n$ in terms of the input coordinates is given. The input coordinates are $a_1$ through $a_{n-1}$. Unless you can express $a_n$ as a function of $a_1, ,,., a_{n-1}$, you cannot use it in the definition of $h$.

Comment: I strongly suggest you follow Ryszard Szwarc's suggest of solving it for the $n=3$ case first. In particular, for $\Bbb R^3$. The method for solving that special case will be very informative for solving the general problem.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Can you somehow help me with this? Because I don't want to shorten my proof, because this is the prof that I gave on my exam, and my professor didn;t give me any credit for it. And I want to understand where I did wrong. He told me that it's not that the proof isn't correct, but like you said, it's hard to follow through.

Comment: I've already pointed out a serious flaw. That flaw makes the rest of the proof worthless, as it all buids on the flaw. You do not need to shorten this proof. You need to abandon it, and find one that actually works. Here is a hint: if we were talking about complex vector spaces, then we could find invariant subspaces of dimension $1$, a fact that is quite famous - perhaps the most important result in linear algebra.

Comment: Yes. There is another proof for this problem: If there is an eigenvalue with two eigenvectors, this can be the subspace, if there is 2 eigenvalues, with 1 vector space each, this could be the subspace, and the one you suggested. If there is 1 eigenvalue with complex eigenvector, we can take the subspace of span of the real and the complex one. @PaulSinclair

Comment: @PaulSinclair But you don't think that I can somehow "repair" my proof?

Comment: (1) complex eigenvalues require a complex vector space. Complex vector spaces have "complex" vectors, not "real" vectors (the quotes are because that is a vast oversimplification). There is no guarantee (at least in even dimensions) of an operator on a real vector space having even one eigenvalue. Eigenvectors are indeed my hint, but the solution is trickier than you think. (2) No, I do not see how you can rescue that proof. Identifying an invariant subspace is not so easy. I suggest considering the sequence $v, f(v), f^2(v), \dots$ for some $v\ne 0$.

Comment: If you were to check this proof in an exam, how much would you give it out of 18? Becuase I got 0 and I really thought I did something :-< I get that this proof is not correct, and I know that even if you were to say 17/18 it wouldn't change anything, yet, I will start my second year in this degree soon, and I just thought that the exam that my professor gave me was so hard!! Out of 14 people, only 3 of us passed(barely)

Comment: @PaulSinclair Moreover, how do you think I can get people to upvote my questions? Because as to what I saw on this site, people don't like giving upvotes for checking proofs, and I think that if I woudl ask more qeustions on this site, it would be verification questions.  I'm asking you becuase I saw at your profile that you are in the top 1% on this site, whatever that means.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot judge how harsh your professor is, as I do not know the course, nor the material that has been presented. I'm afraid I would not give credit for this proof either, as it veered off course almost at the start, and as I said, as a result the rest of the proof is moot. Don't take that too far to heart, though. I can recall doing something similar when I was in college (my mistake was thinking convergence on a compact set is uniform - continuity is, but not convergence).

Comment: As for getting upvotes. I'm only middling in the rankings of those of us who answer questions. The 1% is based solely on the amount of activity (posts and comments), and includes hundreds of people.  I'm not really a good person to ask about this, as I don't contribute a lot to the moderation activities.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!